# Delete only one of the duplicated elements in ArrayList

Tags: javascript, arraylist, filter, duplicates, google-cloud-firestore

I have a few arrays, which are filled with different values every new time. So the array sometimes contains more than one of the same value. So it could look like this: `[0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0]`. I want to be able to remove one instance of a target value. For example, if the target were `0`, the array might then look like this: `[0, 0, 2, 3, 0]`.

At the moment I am working with this code:
`var new_list = grades.filter(e => e !== grade);`
Note: grades is the ArrayList I get from the database. But this line is going to remove all 0. But I only want to remove one of the 0.
**EDIT:**
Tried something like this:

```
let grades = doc.data()[grade_type] || [];
var elementIndex = grades.indexOf(grade);
grades.splice(elementIndex);
```

But does not work. Example ArrayList `[0, 0, 0]` . Output `[]`.

~filip

Comment: which zero do you want to delete? or would you like to delete the first found duplicate?

Comment: @NinaScholz Which 0 should be removed is not important:)

Comment: Note this code: `var new_list = grades.filter(e => e !== grade);` will filter all elements that are different from `grade`, but if you have `N` **equal** values different from grade on you array, they all will be returned. So, no duplicated will be removed.

Comment: Just FYI, `ArrayList` is a Java term for their specific implementation of arrays. Javascript only has "arrays".

Comment: Another thing what will help to clarify your problem, if you have this array: `[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]` you want to get as output `[0,1,1,1,2,2,2]` or `[0,1,1,2,2]`?

Comment: @Shidersz The first one

Comment: @FilipDegenhart you can check if my answer helps you... Otherwise, let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you detect which element has duplicates you can use [`splice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

```
grades.splice(elementIndex,1);
```

Comment: But how to find out the elementIndex?

Comment: `grades.indexOf(0)` will give you the index. You may need to use a loop to count all the elements of the array and then find the index and splice each of the elements that repeats more than one time.

Comment: You have to explicity write you want to remove only one item : `grades.splice(elementIndex,1);` . add the second parameter and your code will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help#

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the second appearance of the same value and take a flag for keeping all other values.

```js
var array = [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3],
    f = {};

array = array.filter(v => f.all || (f.all = !(f[v] = (f[v] || 0) + 1 !== 2)));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
The following will remove the second instance of a duplicate (the earliest we can detect that a duplicate, in fact, exists):

```
function removeOneTargetDuplicate(list, target) {
  let result = [];
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] === target) {
      count++;
      if (count === 2) {
        continue;
      }
    }
    result.push(list[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The following solution will remove the first instance of a duplicate, albeit with a bit more complexity but still with linear time complexity:

```
function removeOneTargetDuplicate(list, target) {
  let result = [];
  let duplicate = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    // duplicate will only be true if we've removed the first duplicate
    if (list[i] === target && !duplicate) {

      // if we've found the target, check the rest of the array for a duplicate
      for (let j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
        if (list[j] === target) {
          duplicate = true;
        }
      }

      // if that duplicate was found, skip to the next iteration of the for loop and don't add to the result, effectively removing the first instance of the target
      if (duplicate) {
        continue;
      }
    }
    result.push(list[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Sorry for the misunderstanding but I want to delete a special number (var grade) and if that grade is more than one time in the ArrayList delete them.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my solution above to address that use case

Answer (score 0):

Check next approach, here we loop over the array until we found the first duplicate of the element you want to remove, when we found it, we remove it using [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
const grades = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4];

const rmOneDupFrom = (arr, n) =>
{
    let nCounter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        nCounter = arr[i] === n ? nCounter + 1 : nCounter;

        if (nCounter > 1)
        {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}

console.log("Original => ", JSON.stringify(grades));

// Remove one duplicate of element 3.
rmOneDupFrom(grades, 3);
console.log("one 3 removed => ", JSON.stringify(grades));

// Remove one duplicate of element 0.
rmOneDupFrom(grades, 0);
console.log("one 0 removed => ", JSON.stringify(grades));

// Try to remove one duplicate of element 4.
rmOneDupFrom(grades, 4);
console.log("none removed (4 hasn't duplicates) => ", JSON.stringify(grades));
```

You should note that this approach mutates the original array, in case you don't want that, you can make a copy of the original array before passing it to `rmOneDupFrom()` with [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), example:

```js
let grades = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4];

const rmOneDupFrom = (arr, n) =>
{
    let nCounter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        nCounter = arr[i] === n ? nCounter + 1 : nCounter;

        if (nCounter > 1)
        {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}

let gradesCopy = grades.slice(0);
rmOneDupFrom(gradesCopy, 3);
console.log("Original => ", JSON.stringify(grades));
console.log("Copy => ", JSON.stringify(gradesCopy));
```